# Optimize join 4 Tables with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Query is taking too long. How I can optimize it?

```sql
SELECT a.a1 as r1, b.b1 as r2, c.c1 as r3, d.d1 as r4
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.a_id
LEFT JOIN d ON b.id = d.b_id
WHERE a.id = {id};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `left join` query, your options are to focus on the first table.  This suggests indexes on:

- `a(id)`
- `b(a_id, b_id)`
- `c(a_id)`
- `d(b_id`

You can also include the columns being selected *after* these columns.

If `a.id` is declared as the primary key and the other columns are declared using foreign key relationships, then MySQL creates (almost exactly) these indexes -- and the performance should be good.

Note that most databases do not create indexes with `foreign key` declaration, but MySQL does.

Comment: I need to optimize last join. I don't need to load all data from ```d``` table in my case, but it happens.

Comment: @daviondk . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.